# Cakephp: How can I get the last value from another table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My question is not very clear so let me explain. English is not my first language so, sorry if I'm not clear.

I have two tables: "backups" and "backups_clients".
The ID column in "backups" is named "idBackup" and in my "backups_clients" table, I have a foreign key "idBackup" link to this column.

Foreach backup, there's X number of backup client. So, a backup can have multiples backups client but a backup client can only have one backup.

In my "backups_clients" table, there's a "date" column and in my "backups" table, there's a "date_last_backup" column.

In my index view, I have a table with every inserted backup. There's one empty column.
In the empty column, I want to display the date from the last inserted backup client.

What should I put in my BackupController and in my index view?

This is what I have in my index function in BackupController:

```
public function index() {
    $query = $this->Backups
        ->find('search', ['search' => $this->request->query])
        ->contain(['Clients', 'BackupsClient']);

    $this->set('backups', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('isSearch', $this->Backups->isSearch());

    $clients = $this->Backups->Clients->find('list');
    $this->set('clients', $clients );

    $backups_client = $this->Backups->BackupsClient->find('list');
    $this->set('backups_client', $backups_client );

}
```

Comment: Do you ever actually use `$clients` and `$backups_client` in your view? That information should already be in your `$backups` because you've contained both of those tables in that query.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to display the `date` column from `backups_clients` or the `date_last_backup` column from `backups`.

Comment: There are a few naming problems. Did you configure everything correctly (because it was not properly named)? In the text you write the table called 'backups_clients', in the code you name the model BackupsClient (and I think BackupClients would be the right Name for the model and backup_clients for the table). If you have linked BackupClients in the Backups Model (Table) (probably with hasMany), just enter an sort there `$this->hasMany ('BackupClients', ['sort' => ['BackupClients.date '=>' DESC ']]);` so that the first BackupClient entity is the one with the latest date.